# Check for Square Brackets in Datatable.Select

Tags: c#, select, datatable, square-bracket

I would like to know how to do a

```
dataTable.select([Short Description] like '%[%]%').
```

The above line errors out with invalid syntax. Can somebody tell me the right way?

Answer (score 3):

The code should like below:

```
dataTable.select("[Short Description] like '%[%]%'")
```

You forgot to include it in double quotes.

Comment: @NewDeveloper, are you getting run time error or compile time error? It would be better if you provides the whole code.